# Adding more data to an array after import CSV

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm trying to import data from a CSV file and then add an additional header and data to the object.
Example: the CSV contains

```
firstname,lastname,e-mail,telephone
john,doe,jd@jd.com,3015551212
```

I want to add a field `reason` with the value `duplicate`.

At the end I want to export all the updated information to another CSV file.

```
$completelist = '.\NZ-CompleteList.csv'
Import-Csv -Path $CompleteList |
    Group-Object TelephoneExtension |
    Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there:

```
$completelist = '.\NZ-CompleteList.csv'
import-csv -path $CompleteList | Group-Object TelephoneExtension | Where-object {$_.count -gt 1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group | Select-Object *,@{n='Reason';e={'Duplicate'}} | Export-CSV Duplicates.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

EDIT:

Okay. Then

```
$completelist = '.\NZ-CompleteList.csv'
$original = import-csv -path $CompleteList
$export = $original | Group-Object TelephoneExtension | Where-object {$_.count -gt 1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group | Select-Object *,@{n='Reason';e={'Duplicate'}}
$export += $original | Group-Object TelephoneExtension | Where-object {$_.count -eq 1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group | Select-Object *,@{n='Reason';e={'Unique'}}
$export | Export-CSV Updated.CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to preserve the sorting...

```
$completelist = '.\NZ-CompleteList.csv'
$original = import-csv -path $CompleteList

$Original | Select-Object *,@{n='Reason';e={$t = $_.TelephoneExtension; IF (($Original | ?{$_.TelephoneExtension -eq $t}).count -gt 1) {"Duplicate"} ELSE {"Unique"}}} | Export-CSV Updated.CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

Preserve sorting and update the original file

```
$completelist = '.\NZ-CompleteList.csv'
$original = import-csv -path $CompleteList

$export = $Original | Select-Object *,@{n='Reason';e={$t = $_.TelephoneExtension; IF (($Original | ?{$_.TelephoneExtension -eq $t}).count -gt 1) {"Duplicate"} ELSE {"Unique"}}}
$export | export-csv $completelist -notypeinformation
```

In my experience you can't read the contents of a file and overwrite that file on the same line.

Comment: Almost there; This writes the duplicates to a new file, it does not update the original file as requested.

Comment: actually, would it be possible to update the records in the same file?:-)